# Having problems in passing an array to a method in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiI07.png)I have created a class in which a method accepts two arrays as parameters. There I have defined it as:

```
myMethod(int []x, int []y){
   //Code
}
```

[sampleInputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRQke.png)

I want to access the class method in main, by `MyClass.myMethod({1,2,3},{4,5,6})`

Not by `new int[]{1,2,3}...`

Is there any way to do that?
Note: I cannot edit the main class. So whatever can be done inside the method body is required.

Thanks for your time.

My Code:
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {

```
public static int solution(int[] x, int[] y) {
    // Your code here
   
    int[] shorter = (x.length>y.length)?  y : x;
    int[] longer = (x.length>y.length)?  x : y;
    
    Arrays.sort(shorter);
    Arrays.sort(longer);
    
    for(int i=0; i<shorter.length; i++){
        if(shorter[i]!=longer[i]){
            System.out.println(longer[i]);
            return longer[i];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(longer[longer.length-1]);
            return longer[longer.length-1];
        }
            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: *I want to access the class method in main, by MyClass.myMethod({1,2,3},{4,5,6})* You can't as that's incorrect initialisation. But why would you want to?

Comment: You cannot pass array parameters like that (`myMethod({1,2,3},{4,5,6})`), so there is nothing you can do with your method declaration to make that work.

Comment: You can't do that, because the compiler allow this kind of initialize in only one case. When you declare variable: `int[] temp = {1,2,3};`

Comment: MyClass.myMethod({1,2,3},{4,5,6}) is MyClass is the class name then it would not work unless myMethod is static method if it public or protected then you need an object of it's class
{1,2,3} is not array but new Int[]{1,2,3} so you need it to be like that to work

Comment: Unfortunately this is not how the compiler works. Typically the compiler needs explicit context of the data type in the array. This is done with the `new int[]` portion of the declaration in this case. It's not needed in `int[] example = {1, 2, 3};` because it can infer from the `int[] example` portion the array is meant to be `int`. But in the case of a parameter, there's no explicit declaration telling the compiler to expect a `int[]` with the text `{1, 2, 3}`. There might be a point that maybe it should be adjusted to infer from the method header, but that's not how it currently works.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JoachimSauer , I am really sorry, I am new to this. Attached my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the main class, but have full controll over the Solution-Class, you can change the solution-method to use String parameters, wich you can then turn to int[] inside the Method.

```
public static int solution(String xStr, String yStr){
    int[] x = splitString(xStr);
    int[] y = splitString(yStr);

    ...
}

public static int[] splitString(String s) {
    String[] array = s.substring(1, s.length() - 2).split(",");
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       result[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
    }
        
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the input is given as Solution.solution({1,2,3}, {4,5,6}). The arguments are not String. Are these arguments of any type first of all??